# Add a Description to a plot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created plots from an imported Excel that was converted into a Dataframe. Now I want to add a Description either left or underneath of the Plots I created. I'm using Seaborn Violinplots.
I have my code below.
I now want to add the mean Values beneath or beside these Plots and maybe also add some text. I'm new to seaborn and haven't found anything on the web, maybe I searched wrong whatever, so help is greatly appreciated.
I have attached a Image with my plot, next to it I would like a textbox with whatever I want in it, either the mean value or a text.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
df = excel_file.parse('Sheet1')
series = ['Name1', 'Name2']

with PdfPages(r'\\Desktop\Charts.pdf') as export_pdf:
    df8 = df[['Column', 'Column.1']].copy()
    f8, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10,4))
    sns.violinplot(data=df8, inner="quartile", orient='v', palette='Set2', ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_title('Plot8', size=18)
    plt.ylabel('Value', fontsize=12)
    plt.xlabel('Count', fontsize=12)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(series)
    ax1.set_ylim(60, 160)
    ax1.axhline(y=85, color='orange')
    ax1.axhline(y=110, color='green')
    export_pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

[image: Image of Plot]

Comment: Try this:`g=sns.violinplot(...);g.text(0.25,80,'test text')`

Comment: that does plot a text box thank you, however how can I be sure it's always outside of the plot? Anyway thank you

Comment: and how do I draw a rectangle around it?